# filter select multiple angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner with Angular and i have a multiple select in order to filter a list by name.

```
<select multiple ng-options="data.name for data in datas" ng-model="filterData">
</select>
```

I can filter with only one value by doing this :

`<div class="container " data-ng-repeat="data in datas | filter : filterData[0].name">`

but in my case i want to pass an array to the filter in order to filter with multiple values in same time

I must to create my own filter to do this ?

```
{
         "datas": [
            {"name": "first", "id": 1},
            {"name": "two", "id": 2},
            {"name": "three", "id": 3},
        ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('myController', myController);

  function myController($scope) {
    $scope.datas = [{
      "name": "first",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "two",
      "id": 2
    }, {
      "name": "three",
      "id": 3
    }, ];

    $scope.filterData = [];

    $scope.byArray = function(myArray) {
      return function(item) {
        return !myArray.some(function(word) {
          return item.name.indexOf(word.name) > -1;             
        });
      };

    }
  }
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select multiple ng-multible="true" size="3" ng-options="data.name for data in datas" ng-model="filterData">
  </select>
  <div class="container" data-ng-repeat="data in datas | filter : byArray(filterData)">{{data.name}}
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. i just added a condition to display all datas by default without filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom filter and pre-define some filter values:

```
<div class="container " data-ng-repeat="data in datas | filter : byArray">

var _filterTheseWords = ["first", "two", "three"];
$scope.byArray = function(item) {
    return _filterTheseWords.some(word) {
        return item.name.indexOf(word) > -1;
    });
}
```